# ts-node throws unrelated strange error, but no error was thrown when using tsc

Tags: typescript, ts-node

When i run ts-node, it throw me these error

```
src/api/role.ts:2:58 - error TS2774: This condition will always return true since the function is always defined. Did you mean to call it instead?
2 var __createBinding = (this && this.__createBinding) || (Object.create ? (function(o, m, k, k2) {
                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/api/role.ts:9:64 - error TS2774: This condition will always return true since the function is always defined. Did you mean to call it instead?
9 var __setModuleDefault = (this && this.__setModuleDefault) || (Object.create ? (function(o, v) {
```

But all the lines mentioned in the error can't be found in my code.
I tried to run tsc, it did not show those errors. All these error only happens when i use ts-node.

Answer (score 0):

i changed my `_moduleAliases` in package.json to refer to built script. and it work, but for every change in my script i need to run `tsc`.

Comment: why dont you use `tsc --watch` ?